# Projectiles passing through other entities

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, bounding-box

I wrote a collision detection system for a game I am working on, and I am experiencing a weird glitch where, occasionally, projectiles will go through the player or walls scattered throughout the level.  Because the projectiles can be fired at any angle, I decomposed the bounding box of each projectile into multiple, smaller bounding boxes that I then rotate around the center of the texture according to the rotation of the projectile in space.  For some reason, occasionally a Spear projectile will go through the player or a wall even through others do not.

I use the following methods to determine the rotation of the texture and to translate the bounding boxes:

```
        public double RotateToFaceTarget()
    {
        double rotation = Math.Atan2((double)_direction.Y, (double)_direction.X);
        return rotation;
    }
    public List<BoundingBox> TranslateBoundingBox(List<BoundingBox> box, double rotation)
    {
        List<BoundingBox> newBounds = new List<BoundingBox>();
        foreach (BoundingBox b in box)
        {
            Vector2 boundsOrigin = new Vector2(b.Pos.X + b.Size.X / 2, b.Pos.Y + b.Size.Y / 2);
            Vector2 texOrigin = new Vector2(_pos.X + _texture.Width / 2, _pos.Y + _texture.Height / 2);

            Vector2 newPosBasedOnOrigin = Vector2.Transform(boundsOrigin - texOrigin, Matrix.CreateRotationZ((float)rotation)) + boundsOrigin;

            newBounds.Add(new BoundingBox(newPosBasedOnOrigin, b.Size));
        }
        return newBounds;
    }
```

_direction is calculated by subtracting the position of the projectile from the target location and normalizing.  I use this method to determine if the projectile is colliding with another entity:

```
        public bool ProjectileCollision(Entity e, Projectile entity2)
    {
        if (entity2.CanCollide)
        {
            foreach(GameObject.BoundingBox b in entity2.BoundingBox)
            {
                foreach(GameObject.BoundingBox b2 in e.BoundingBox)
                {
                    if (b2.Intersect(b) && (entity2.IgnoredEntities.Contains(e.Type) == false))
                    {
                        entity2.IsActive = false;
                        e.Health -= entity2.Damage;
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And this is my Bounding Box Intersection method:

```
        public bool Intersect(BoundingBox intersected)
    {
        if ((_pos.Y < intersected.Pos.Y + intersected.Size.Y) && (_pos.Y + _size.Y > intersected.Pos.Y) && (_pos.X + _size.X > intersected.Pos.X) && (_pos.X < intersected.Pos.X + intersected.Size.X))
        { return true; }
        return false;
    }
```

EDIT: On further testing, it seems that the projectile will always detect a hit if the player hits based on the top left corner ( which makes sense now that I look at my intersect code). Is there another way to re-write my Intersect method to use something more accurate than the top left corner?

EDIT2: I drew the hitboxes for certain objects, and this is one instance of when I catch the spear going through the player:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcrKW.jpg

the player is the larger pink square.  The hitboxes are not being translated correctly, but it shouldn't just stop working, for some and not others, right?

Comment: This has happened to me on occasion. Is the velocity of the projectile greater than the width of the target? If so, it might 'skip over' during the update loop.

Comment: The player hitbox is 32x32 and the velocity of the projectile is at most 15.

Comment: I can think of a few cases where it jumping 15 pixels would cause it to skip a legitimate hit, just not head on, which explains why this behavior only occurs sometimes. My immediate thought is to split up the position being checked into some number of slices (say, 10) of the old and new positions if the two things being compared are roughly near each other. Then use _those-_ to check if the projectile would have passed through

Comment: It seems to occur most often at angles around 45 degrees (+- about 10), which could explain the problem.  Any suggestions of how to get around this?

Comment: On further testing, it seems that the projectile will always detect a hit if the player hits based on the top left corner ( which makes sense now that I look at my intersect code).  Is there another way to re-write my Intersect method to use something more accurate than the top left corner?

Comment: I drew the hitboxes for certain objects, and this is one instance of when I catch the spear going through the player:  

http://imgur.com/a/fAxZw

the player is the larger pink square.  The hitboxes are not being translated correctly, but it shouldn't just stop working, for some and not others, right?

Comment: It also seems that, the more spears there are, the likelihood of a hit registering decreases.

Answer (score 0):

It could happen, because of high velocity and small object, projectile could fly through object. Beside of checking if objects are intersecting, you have to check if object **will** intersect, to check if object is in line of fire. You could achieve this by raycasting.

On those cases like your i had function that check if object is near other. Simple checking if object is inside of some radius of other object. If yes then i was checking if object is flying toward other object, and checking distance between them. When distance is really close then collision happened.